# Higher regularity of weak solution for Laplace equation with Robin condition

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde

From [Grisvard, Thm. 2.4.2.7, p. 126], the BVP 
\begin{align}
-\Delta u &= 0 & \text{in}\ \Omega\\
-\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + au &= g & \text{on}\ \Gamma\\
\end{align}
where $a>0$ and $g \in H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$ has unique solution $u$ with $H^2$ regularity for open bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with boundary $\Gamma$ of class $C^{1,1}$.

**Question** For $C^{2,1}$ boundary $\Gamma$ and $g \in H^{3/2}(\Gamma)$, is it true that $u \in H^3(\Omega)$? and, in general, is it true that $u \in H^{k+2}(\Omega)$ for $C^{k+1,1}$ boundary $\Gamma$ and $g \in H^{k+1/2}(\Gamma)$.